# Get value of items from list using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```
<script>
  function getgroup(){

        var i=0;
        var total=document.getElementById("selectedOptions").length;

    while (i<total)
  {
    var group=document.getElementById("selectedOptions").value;
    var group2=group.substring(2);

    alert(group2);
     i++;
}
}
</Script>
```

I want to loop inside the list and get the value of each item in the list.
By using this code I am getting only the value of the first item only.

Any help please?

Comment: There should only exist one object with a unique id.  It's obvious there will be only one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the value of the select element to the group variable. You need to loop through the options instead:

```
group = document.getElementById("selectedOptions").options[i].value;
```

Comment: Just a small thing, I want to sum() the group value, I did `var group3=group3+group2;` but it is not calculating

Comment: What is the result you're getting? You might have to use `parseInt` on the variables to be able to sum them up.

Comment: `var group2=parseInt(group.substring(2));` I got NaN as a result

Comment: What kind of values do you have on your options? They have to be numbers of some kind if you want to add them together, which they are not if you get a `NaN` result.

Comment: Example1: G.132, I am getting the number (132) - Example2: G.125 and so on

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong. Some part of your calculation is a string that cannot be converted to a number. Check out this jsfiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qwh52/

Answer (score 2):

i think u are using `getElementById()` method and by specification the ids of elements should be unique so the length will always be one. try adding a class and use `getElementsByClass()`

Comment: Given that the element with id "selectedOptions" is a select, `length` will contain the number of options in that select.

Comment: but here nowhere it is mentioned.. i know this.. anyways thankx